# Como omitir um item específico do ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Possuo esse trecho de código abaixo para carregar um comboBox com o 'name' de todos values e está funcionando corretamente.

```js
<select
    ng-model="information"
    ng-options="value.id as value.name for value in information">   
</select>
```

Porém preciso excluir do carregamento o value.name cujo id seja igual a 301.
  Como faço para carregar todos value.name, exceto o value.name que tenha o id igual a 301?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que teria que construir um filter e aplica-lo na variável `information`.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode aplicar um [filtro](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) por correspondência de objeto, negando esse id específico, assim:

```
<select
    ng-model="information"
    ng-options="value.id as value.name for value in information | filter: {id: '!301'}">   
</select>
```

<sup>http://plnkr.co/edit/adxtpqwoVvldt4rLEDJv?p=preview</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Para não deixar o código 'chumbado' no ID: 301, passo uma solução mais elegante.

no controller, você pode adicionar uma regra de négocio, e marca seu objeto como checado, para true ou false, (false no caso do seu ID)

```
angular.forEach(information, function(value, index){
    //Adicionar regra de negócio aqui.
    if(regra)
       value.checked = true;
    else
       value.checked = false;
});
```

no html utilizar assim.

```
<select
    ng-model="information"
    ng-options="value.id as value.name for value in information | filter: {checked: true}">   
</select>
```

assim você pode bloquear N registros de acordo com sua regra de negócio, por que se alterar de BD, sua aplicação não vai realizar tal tratamento se o ID for outro.

Comment: Ou seja, chumba o 301 no controller, é isso?

Comment: sim vai dar certo, porém eu não chumbaria o 301, por que se trocar de base de dados, com toda certeza não vai ser mais esse ID, ou seja, não vai funcionar, eu adicionaria a REGRA, que não se aplica ao 301

Comment: Entendo, mas da maneira como ele colocou a pergunta talvez não exista regra.